# Is this map linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this map linear?

### $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+2x_2+3,x_2+2x_1,3x_1)$

Thank you very much! I thought it is not linear because there is a constant, which causes $T(v)+T(u)$ not to equal to $T(v+u)$.

Comment: I assume there should not be a "$T$" on the right-hand side. Then your reasoning is fine. Another way to justify it is to note $T(0,0) \ne (0,0,0)$.

Comment: @angryavian Yeah thanks a lot! I've changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=(x_1,y_1)$ and $v=(x_2,y_2)$.

For a transformation to be linear, two conditions must hold: $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ and $T(cu)=cT(u)$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (a quicker, one step test is to check $T(c_1u+c_2v)=c_1T(u)+c_2T(v)$)

Consider $T(cu)$

$T(cu)=T((cx_1,cy_1))=(cx_1+2cy_1+3,cy_1+2cx_1,3cx_1)$
$cT(u)=cT((x_1,y_1))=(cx_1+2cy_1+3c,cy_1+2cx_1,3cx_1)$

These differ in the first component, therefore the transformation isn’t linear.